# When will onRetainCustomNonConfigurationInstance gets called ? Does it get called during locale change from device side?

Tags: android, locale, android-fragmentactivity, android-configchanges

In my Activity I have a function called `onRetainCustomNonConfigurationInstance()`. I have added a log to see if it gets called anytime. And I'm not getting any log from it.

The scenario is such that during locale change from device settings, I need to retain some data and reuse it. Sadly it looks like the function is not at all getting called and `getLastCustomNonConfigurationInstance()` returns null always.

Answer (score 1):

`onRetainCustomNonConfigurationInstance` is useful to store an object during ***configuration changes*** in your app, e.g. orientation change.

You can find more about this method here:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

Unfortunately, this is not going to help you with your problem in any way as locale changes is not an application configuration change, but rather a device configuration change. In order to detect the latter you need a [BroadcastReceiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) and receive the [ACTION_LOCALE_CHANGED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_LOCALE_CHANGED) Intent.